# Wordpress pagination is not working when don't preserve the initial query object

Tags: php, wordpress

On a custom page template on my custom theme I have the below query. When I do it this way the pagination is working :

```
 $myqueryname = $wp_query;
 $mypost_args = array( 'post_type' => 'friends', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged' => $paged);
 $wp_query = new WP_Query($mypost_args);
 while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

    Some html.....

 endwhile;

 previous_posts_link('Prev');
 next_posts_link('Next');
```

But when I am using this way the pagination is not working :

```
$mypost_args = array( 'post_type' => 'friends', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost_args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         Some html.....

endwhile;

previous_posts_link('Prev');
next_posts_link('Next');
wp_reset_query();
```

I was wondering why is this happening ? What is the difference ? Sorry if my question is vague but this will help me to understand better the way wordpress is working and not just copy-paste codes from forums.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the [code](http://wpseek.com/get_next_posts_link/) of the get_next_posts_link (function that `next_posts_link` calls) it has the following code:

```
global $paged, $wp_query;

if ( !$max_page )
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
...
```

And this is the usage of [next_posts_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_posts_link)

```
 <?php next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages ); ?>
```

It looks to me that when you use custom query you need to specify `$max_pages` for pagination to work.

Try modifying your pagination code to this:

```
previous_posts_link('Prev', $loop->max_num_pages);
next_posts_link('Next', $loop->max_num_pages);
```